# Magentic dipole moment

Tags: electromagnetism

Multipole expansion for the vector potential is given by:

$$A(r)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\iiint\frac{J(r')}{|r-r'|}dV'=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac1r\iiint J(r')\left[1+\left(\frac{r'}r\right)\cos(\alpha)+\cdots\right]dV'$$
($\alpha$ is the angle between $r$ and $r'$)

For a localised distrbitution of charge and currents: $$\int J(r)dV= \frac{dp}{dt}$$

The volume integral of the current density $J$ is equal to the time rate of change of the systems dipole moment $p$

But $dp/dt=0$ if the current is steady because the charge density would be constant with time and so the monopole term in the multipole expansion of the vector potential is always zero in magnetostatics.

Thus we have:

$$A_{\text{monopole}}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac1r\iiint J(r')dV'=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac1r\frac{dp}{dt}=0$$

This shows that there is no monopole term.

As for the dipole term, we should expect there to be an analogous magnetic dipole moment for a system of current which is defined as:

$$m=\frac12\iiint r\times J(r)\,dV$$

With this definition we can write the dipole as:

$$A_{\text{dipole}}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{m\times r}{r^2}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{m\times\hat r}{|r|^3}$$

I was wondering why the dipole term is non-zero considering $dp/dt=0$ from above, this means that $m=0$ as well.

Comment: Why is m=0? I cant see that.

Comment: Because we have: $$\int J(r)dV= \frac{dp}{dt}$$

This means:  $$ m = \frac{1}{2} \int r \times J(r) dV=\frac{1}{2} r \times \int J(r) dV= \frac{1}{2} r \times \frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{1}{2} r \times 0 = 0$$

Comment: I see,you cannot pull the r out of the integral like that,since it is also included in the integration.